# How to use value from select in fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I need to choose the city in Select and then insert it to the fetch to get weather forecast of the user selected city, but I got this message before I got a chance to choose something:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: strUser is not defined:

```
document.querySelector(".city-select").onchange = () => {
    let strUser = document.querySelector(".city-select").value;
}

fetch(`'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${strUser}&appid=f3ab273b1163fcf008d6dce02f9e86e'`)
    .then(function (resp) { return resp.json() })
    .then(function (data) {
        document.querySelector('.package-name').textContent = data.name;
        document.querySelector('.temp').innerHTML = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273) + '&deg;';
    })
    .catch(function () {
    });
```

Comment: Because you’ve used `let` the `strUser` variable is scoped within the anonymous function of the event-handler you’ve defined. Also you’ve wrapped the URL of your `fetch` call in both back-ticks *and* single-quotes, this seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `strUser` variable is scoped to the `change` event handler.

You seem to want to repeat the `fetch` whenever that value changes, so I'd suggest putting the `fetch` in a function you can then call any time you want to update the information it shows. For instance:

```
document.querySelector(".city-select").onchange = () => {
    let strUser = document.querySelector(".city-select").value;
    updateInfo(strUser);
};

function updateInfo(strUser) {
    fetch(`'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${strUser}&appid=f3ab273b1163fcf008d6d3ce02f9e86e'`)
        .then(function (resp) { return resp.json() })
        .then(function (data) {
            document.querySelector('.package-name').textContent = data.name;
            document.querySelector('.temp').innerHTML = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273) + '&deg;';
        })
        .catch(function () {
            // Best to handle/report the error here
        });
}
```

---

Side note: You don't need to re-query the DOM to find the element the `change` happened on if you use a traditional function rather than an arrow function; you can use `this` within the function instead:

```
document.querySelector(".city-select").onchange = function() {
    let strUser = this.value;
    updateInfo(strUser);
};
```

Side note 2: Your code is falling prey to a bit of a footgun in the `fetch` API (I write about it [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)). `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors, so your code may end up calling `json` when it's received a 500 or 404 error or similar. You have to do the check for HTTP success explicitly (which is why I always wrap `fetch` in a utility function):

```
fetch(`'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${strUser}&appid=f3ab273b1163fcf008d6d3ce02f9e86e'`)
    .then(function (resp) {
        if (!resp.ok) {                                   // ***
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + resp.status); // ***
        }                                                 // ***
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        document.querySelector('.package-name').textContent = data.name;
        document.querySelector('.temp').innerHTML = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273) + '&deg;';
    })
    .catch(function () {
        // Best to handle/report the error here
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are getting the error is because `let` keyword has block scope and cannot be accessed within your `fetch()`;

Also, `fetch()` is asynchronous.

Best solution would be to wrap your fetch call inside a function and only once the `strUser` is available call it. Try this:

```
document.querySelector(".city-select").onchange = () => {
    let strUser = document.querySelector(".city-select").value;
    getDetails(strUser);
}


function getDetails(strUser){
  fetch(`'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${strUser}&appid=f3ab273b1163fcf008d6dce02f9e86e'`)
    .then(function (resp) { return resp.json() })
    .then(function (data) {
        document.querySelector('.package-name').textContent = data.name;
        document.querySelector('.temp').innerHTML = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273) + '&deg;';
    })
    .catch(function () {
    });
}
```